# Subtract Values From Two SELECT Statements Iteratively In MYSQL

Tags: mysql

how would I subtract two values iteratively from two tables in MySQL? The code below works for one nick, but I would like MySQL to iterate over all nicks in the 'points' table.

Here is the working code for one nick value:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(points_log.amount) FROM points_log WHERE nick='prestonconnors' GROUP BY nick)
-
(SELECT SUM(points.amount) FROM points WHERE nick='prestonconnors' GROUP by nick)
```

Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can join the two tables maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT points.nick, SUM(points_log.amount) - SUM(points.amount) 
FROM points 
JOIN points_log ON points.nick = points_log.nick
GROUP BY points.nick
```

Comment: That executes, but the results aren't what I expected. I got -290796.3450 when searching for prestonconnors in the output, but when I do the above statement I originally posted I get 30.2400 (which is what I expect).

Comment: That's odd, it should give the same output I believe. Let me look into it.

Comment: It was an error on my part. The points table is already summed, so the SUM(points.amount) statement was summing up the entire points table in your example but only summing the single entry in the original post by me. I will accept your answer as correct. Thanks!